# How can we create our own custom validation

Tags: grails, sdn

I am using grails 2.4.3 with database Neo4j with SDN ,We don't use Grails plugin so grails doesn't support Neo4j and if we create our domain classes in domain package then it gives us an error. 
So We create our domain in Services package. My First Question is:

We are right or we have to do another thing?

My another question is to provide the validation in this concept. We use the Command Object for it. So now we need some Custom validation for unique. I know we can use Validator for it, but we want that our logic only remain in Services. So can we create something like this?

```
static constraints = {
        username size: 5..15
        password size: 5..15, blank: false
        userEmail email: true
        }
username email:true 
userName name:unique
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're so fixated on having to use a service for this. Creating a service annotated with `@Validateable` and using it as a non-GORM domain class seems very weird. If it works, cool, but it's sort of like driving to work in reverse the whole way. You'll get there (until you burn out the transmission) but it'll be a stressful drive looking in the rear view mirror and seeing everthing reversed the whole time.

Why not just put the classes in a sensible package under src/groovy and annotate those? You just need to register them in `Config.groovy`, e.g.

```
grails.validateable.classes = [
     com.mycompany.myapp.User, com.mycompany.dto.Account]
```

You can do a uniqueness check, but not with the standard `unique` constraint. That's tied to GORM; it looks at the table or backing store for you domain class and runs a datastore-specific uniqueness query, but that doesn't apply here. But you can easily do the same thing yourself. Use a custom validator:

```
email validator: { value, obj ->
   // run a Neo4j query checking to see if value has
   // been used, the equivalent of
   // "select count(email) from person where email=?"
   // and return false if the count is not zero
}
```